# how can version A of a software be released AFTER version B when A is (?) older than B

Tags: symfony, versioning

I have been reading a while on the subject and I came across [an article](https://symfony.com/blog/category/releases?page=1) which left me a little bit lost on software versioning/releases.

If you follow it you will see it's just a list of all Symfony releases with their respective dates. What prompted me to ask this question was the fact that I could not get why/how, for example:

> *Symfony 2.8.37 released* | *April 2, 2018*

while

> *Symfony 4.0.6 released* | *March 5, 2018*

Symfony is just the example, my question applies to software versioning in general looking for an explanation to the above.

I am (am I?) positive that ***2.8.37*** is older than ***4.0.6*** so this most certainly has nothing to do with me comparing them wrong, surely there is a fundamental aspect about the versions release process I'm unaware of.

Finally, just to be sure, if I *were* to compare two versions, how would I go about it, I don't need a computer-language-specific-solution, just an algorithm in general to compare two given versions like you could do even using paper and pencil (I know, what a heathen).

Comment: The [road map](https://symfony.com/roadmap) might help.

Comment: @Cerad; I noticed 2.8 has security fixes support until 2019, which means patches and fixes will still be randomly released for this non-current/mayor version at the same time changes for the current version are? thus intertwining in the timeline. was that what I was supposed to notice?

Comment: Pretty much.  Another thing to understand is that each major version (2,3,4,5 etc) breaks compatibility with the previous versions.  So it might help to think of 2 being a completely different version than say 4 even though they still share a great deal of code and design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony has very good support for old versions of their framework. Basically Symfony 2 was released and went through various version changes similar to 2.1 -> 2.2 etc. All the while maintaining compatibility with previous Symfony 2 projects.

Further down the road Symfony 3 was released, and while a Symfony 2 project could be updated to a Symfony 3 project it involves some work and there can be project breaking coding changes required. Then Symfony 3 progress 3.1 -> 3.2 etc.

Just because Symfony 3 is out and available doesn't mean that all work or bug fixes are done on Symfony 2. So there will still be releases of Symfony 2, in addition to releases of Symfony 3. Here is a visual view from the [Symfony Page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html) to show the version overlaps.

[image: Symfony Roadmap from 4/20/2018]

This is common with most software, for example Microsoft Windows 10 is the current version but Microsoft still provides patches for Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, 2.8.38 would be a security or other patch to 2.8.37; and 4.0.6 is a patch to 4.0.5, where 4.0 is a newer, more powerful base version that requires a different license or runs only under Windows 10 or some other reason why some people would like to stay on the old version.

The patch to the current version would be published faster, and then the team adds the important security patch to the older versions.

Comment: so, basically even if your current version is 4.y.z, you would still roll out fixes/patches for old/still-supported versions while you are making changes and releasing sub-versions for the current one, did I get it right?